# VueJS Typescript WebPack, impossible to remove object from array with splice or delete

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, splice

i try to remove a object from array in vueJS but this is impossible.

I tyr a lot of thing and read some solution on stackoverflow but nothing work for me.

I have a fake list like this in my vue.html component :

```
<div class="custo-list-c">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in valuesFounded" 
    @click="addItem(item)"
    v-bind:class="{ 'selected': itemSelected(item) }">
    {{ item.value }}
    <span v-if="itemSelected(item)">
      <i class="fa fa-remove" @click="itemDeleted(item)"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my component look something like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { Prop, Watch, Emit } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  name: 'custolist-component',
  template: require('./custo-list.component.vue.html'),
  components: {}
})
export default class CustoListComponent extends Vue {

  public custoListActive: boolean = false;
  public valuesFounded: Array<{key: string, value: string}> = [];

  public selectedItems_: Array<{key: string, value: string}> = [];

  @Prop() list;
  @Watch('list') onListChanged(newList, oldList) {
    // this.list = newList;
  }

  @Prop() placeholder;
  @Watch('placeholder') onPlaceholderChanged(newPlaceholder, oldPlaceholder) {
    // console.log(newPlaceholder);
  }

  @Prop() disabled;
  @Watch('disabled') onDisabledChanged(newDisabled, oldDisabled) {
    // console.log(newPlaceholder);
  }

  public open(event) {
    this.custoListActive = true;
    if (!event.target.value) {
      this.valuesFounded = this.list;
    } else {
      this.valuesFounded = [];
      const re = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'ig');
      for (var i=0; i<this.list.length; i++) {
        if (this.list[i].key.match(re) || this.list[i].value.match(re)) {
          this.valuesFounded.push(this.list[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public addItem(item: {key: string, value: string}) {

    if (!this.isSelectedItem_(item)) {
      this.selectedItems_.push(item);
      // this.custoListActive = false;
    };

    this.$emit('itemclicked', item);
  }

  public itemSelected(item) {
    return this.isSelectedItem_(item);
  }

  public itemDeleted(item) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.selectedItems_.length; i++) {
      if (item.key == this.selectedItems_[i].key) {
        this.selectedItems_.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    this.$emit('itemdeleted', item);
  }

  private isSelectedItem_(item) {
    const filtered = this.selectedItems_.filter(m => {
      return m.key == item.key;
    });

    return filtered.length > 0;
  }
}
```

but when i do `this.selectedItems_.splice(i, 1);` that does not work !!

Thank for your help

More precisions about my code. Here the method where i remove item from my array :

```
public itemDeleted(item) {
  const filtered = this.selectedItems_.filter(m => {
    return m.key != item.key;
  });

  console.log(filtered, this.selectedItems_.length);
  this.selectedItems_ = filtered;
  console.log(this.selectedItems_, this.selectedItems_.length);

  this.$emit('itemdeleted', item);
}
```

And the result in the console

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCQit.png)

What's wrong?

Another test :

```
  public itemDeleted(item) {
    this.selectedItems_ = this.selectedItems_.filter(m => {
      return m.key != item.key;
    });

    this.selectedItems_.splice(this.selectedItems_.length);
    console.log(this.selectedItems_, this.selectedItems_.length);
    this.selectedItems_ = [];
    console.log(this.selectedItems_, this.selectedItems_.length);

    this.$emit('itemdeleted', item);
  }
```

result :

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCQit.png)

May be a bug VueJS

Sorry, it was my fault, replace

```
<i class="fa fa-remove" @click="itemDeleted(item)"></i>
```

by

```
<i class="fa fa-remove" v-on:click.stop="itemDeleted(item)"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple steps of finding value with combination of `for` loop and `if` statement reduces readability and code predictability. In addition, invoking array mutating method `splice` may not trigger reactive update of this property.

I'd suggest to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and re-assign `selectedItems_` inside `itemDeleted` method as follows:

```
public itemDeleted(item) {
  this.selectedItems_ = this.selectedItems_.filter(selectedItem => selectedItem.key !== item.key)
  this.$emit('itemdeleted', item);
}
```

This way, after method execution, `selectedItems_` will consist of all previous items except the one provided as an argument to the method and all dependent properties will be re-computed.

Comment: Yes, thank @aBiscuit for your answer,  i did that too but nothing change for my problem. On angular splice was not a problem but on vuejs i meet some mistakes. But you right for refactoring.

Comment: Can you verify that `click` handler `itemDeleted` is being invoked after icon is clicked? You can do that, by putting `console.log` statement or `debugger` on the first line of `itemDeleted` method.

Comment: Always itemDeleted is called. All values contained on private var selectedItems_ are Oberver type. This variable is listen as a observer on console.log by vuejs framework. The lenght of the array does not change. May be in need try with vuejs in javascript mode with a simple test.html for see if this problem begin againt

Comment: Please, try changing assignment inside `itemDeleted` method to `this.selectedItems_ = []`. And verify that array length is not changed.

Comment: I tried that too. Really i did a lot of thing but nothing work. May be a problem with my code. I tried to assign a empty array to the variable and clear the list before reassign objet to the list in the loop.

Comment: Alright. How do you measure array length, to verify that it is not changed after `itemDeleted` method being invoked?

Comment: console.log(this.selectedItems_.length). nothing special.

Comment: The only thing very strange is the array length equal zero when i assign a empty array to this.selectedItems_ but in the loop i can parse the array and when it match the condition (item.key == this.selectedItems_[i].key) it try to splice on a key that does not exists in this.selectedItems_.